# Autofilter Macro, used to find a value in a range of data - how to display error message if no data is found

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I have a spreadsheet with a list of employees. I want to run a macro that will filter on a specific employee when the employee number is entered in an input box. However if the number doesn't exist I want an error message to be displayed which gives the option of trying again.

My attempt is below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub AmendWeeklyHours()

'Find employee number
Dim EmployeeNumber As String
Dim Continue As Boolean
Dim aCell As Range

Continue = True

Do While Continue = True
    EmployeeNumber = InputBox("Please enter the employee number", "Enter Employee Number")

If StrPtr(EmployeeNumber) = 0 Then
        '~~> User pressed cancel
        Exit Sub
    Else
        '~~> User pressed OK with something filled
        If EmployeeNumber <> "" Then
            With ActiveSheet
                Set aCell = .Columns(3).Find(What:=EmployeeNumber, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

                If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                    Selection.AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=EmployeeNumber
                    Continue = False
                'If an invalid entry is entered
                Else
                    If MsgBox("You entered an invalid employee number - Try again?", _
                    vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Search again?") = vbNo Then Exit Sub
                    Continue = False
                End If
            End With
        '~~> User pressed OK WITHOUT anything filled
        Else
            MsgBox "You didn't enter a value. Please enter the employee number or press cancel."
            Continue = True
        End If
    End If
Loop


'Find Week Ending Date
Dim WeekEnding As String
Dim Continue1 As Boolean
Dim bCell As Range

Continue1 = True

Do While Continue1 = True
    WeekEnding = InputBox("Please enter the week ending date", "Enter Week Ending Date")

If StrPtr(WeekEnding) = 0 Then
        '~~> User pressed cancel
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
        Exit Sub
    Else
        '~~> User pressed OK with something filled
        If WeekEnding <> "" Then
            With ActiveSheet
                Set bCell = .Columns(6).Find(What:=WeekEnding, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

                If Not bCell Is Nothing Then
                    Selection.AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:=WeekEnding
                    Continue1 = False
                Else
                'If an invalid entry is entered
                    If MsgBox("You entered an invalid week ending date - Try again?", _
                    vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Search again?") = vbNo Then Exit Sub
                    Continue1 = False
                End If
            End With
        Else
            '~~> User pressed OK WITHOUT anything filled
            MsgBox "You didn't enter a value. Please enter the week ending date or press cancel."
            Continue1 = True
        End If
    End If
Loop

'Control + home
Dim Rng As Range
With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter
    Set Rng = .Range.Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Range.Rows.Count - 1)
    Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 1).Select
End With

'Select hours column
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Activate

'Enter hours
Dim NewHours As String
Dim Continue2 As Boolean

Continue2 = True

Do While Continue2 = True
NewHours = InputBox("Please enter the new hours", "Enter New Contracted Hours")

If StrPtr(NewHours) = 0 Then
        '~~> User pressed cancel
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
        Exit Sub

        'User pressed OK WITH something filled
        ElseIf NewHours <> "" Then
        ActiveCell = NewHours
        Continue2 = False
    Else
        '~~> User pressed OK WITHOUT anything filled
        MsgBox "You didn't enter a value. Please enter the number of hours or press cancel."
        Continue2 = True
End If
Loop

'Completion message
MsgBox ("Hours have been amended")

'Show all data
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData    
End Sub
```

**Revised code above**

Comment: had you considered providing the list as a dropdown for the input, so you are not relying upon the user just knowing the numbers?

Comment: What is the use of `EmployeeNumber` if you are not using it? Is `FindVal1` supposed to be `EmployeeNumber`?

Comment: Yeah that could work, would I be able to do that on multiple filters? So for example if I had the employee number listed 7 times for each day of the week could I select '1234' from the dropdown, then have another dropdown for the day of the week? That would leave me with the specific row that I require for the individual. And yes sorry 'FindVal1' is for the employee number.

Comment: You are only checking to see if the EmployeeNumber is an empty string, not if it is a valid employee number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way if you want the user to enter the number

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim EmployeeNumber As String
    Dim Continue As Boolean
    Dim aCell As Range

    Continue = True

    Do While Continue = True
        EmployeeNumber = InputBox("Please enter the assignment number")

        If EmployeeNumber <> "" Then             
            With Sheets("Sheet1")
                '~~> Change .Columns(1) to the relevant range
                Set aCell = .Columns(1).Find(What:=EmployeeNumber, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

                If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                    '~~> Rest of your code
                    'Selection.AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=FindVal1
                Else
                    If MsgBox("You entered an invalid employee number - Try again?", _
                    vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Search again?") = vbNo Then _
                    Continue = False
                End If
            End With
        Else
            Continue = False
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim EmployeeNumber As String
    Dim Continue As Boolean
    Dim aCell As Range

    Continue = True

    Do While Continue = True
        EmployeeNumber = InputBox("Please enter the assignment number")

        If StrPtr(EmployeeNumber) = 0 Then
            '~~> User pressed cancel
            Exit Sub
        Else
            '~~> User pressed OK with something filled
            If EmployeeNumber <> "" Then
                With Sheets("Sheet1")
                    Set aCell = .Columns(3).Find(What:=EmployeeNumber, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

                    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                        Selection.AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=EmployeeNumber
                        Continue = False
                    Else
                        If MsgBox("You entered an invalid employee number - Try again?", _
                        vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Search again?") = vbNo Then _
                        Continue = False
                    End If
                End With
            '~~> User pressed OK WITHOUT anything filled
            Else
                Msgbox "You didn't enter anything. Please enter the employee number in the next box which pops up"
                Continue = True
            End If
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 this is correct however, it seems like re-thinking the entry process would help speed entries and immediately show whether they exist or not. Something similar to data validation is what should be used IMHO.

Comment: Yup you can create a Userform with a Combobox which is pre-populated with the `EmployeeNumber` that a user can select.

Comment: Thanks @SiddharthRout! We have 800 timesheets distributed to our hospital depts. There are 5 rows per employee (5 weeks ending dates per month) with a column for contracted hours. I've locked cells to stop users deleting items by accident (very low level use of IT experience on the wards). To change the hours I needed a macro to say 'select employee', 'select week ending date' then 'enter new hours'. I got it to work (**see revised description**) but the error message box upon an incorrect entry didn't appear. I know it is long winded but it's to automate the process as much as possible.

Comment: Yes that is because you are not checking whether the `EmployeeNumber` exists or not. See my code above on how I am checking for the `EmployeeNumber`...

Comment: With the code above when I entered a valid employee number the message box still came up, is that to do with the loop?

Comment: Yes if the `EmployeeNumber` is not found then you will get the messagebox.

Comment: I have rewritten the code in the desciption above which showcases the full extent of the macro and have made some notes in the revised description :)

Comment: For point 1. Include `Continue = False` after `Selection.AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=EmployeeNumber` Please confirm that it is working and then we will move to point 2.

Comment: Excellent, I included that for week ending date as well and it's worked! It's only the error message box that remains for point 2. I have read that VBA by default recognises US style dates, is that correct?

Comment: It depends on your regional settings.

Comment: This was an early attempt I had for formatting the date as I have it on the timesheet: 'Dim WeekEnding As String
 Dim dDate As Date
    If IsDate(Range("F7:F66")) Then
    dDate = Range("F7:F66")
    dDate = DateSerial(Day(dDate), Month(dDate), Year(dDate))
    End If'

Comment: You cannot put multiple ranges like `IsDate(Range("F7:F66"))` you have to use it like `IsDate(Range("F7"))`

Comment: Ah I see that's okay. One issue I have had is that when I press 'Cancel' on any on of the input boxes it proceeds to the next input box rather than cancelling the macro?

Comment: You mentioned that it jumps from one Inputbox to the other but in your code I can see only one Inputbox?

Comment: Oh okay, I don't know if the revised code is showing up properly in the description. There are three input boxes altogether, the first is 'Employee Number', but if I press cancel it shows the 'Week Ending Date' input box, if I press cancel again it shows the 'Enter Hours' input box. If on any of those input boxes I press cancel I just want the user to return to the workbook if possible.

Comment: Ok change `Continue = False` to `Exit Sub` in the `Else` of `If EmployeeNumber <> "" Then` and `If WeekEnding <> "" Then`

Comment: The 'Cancel' button now works but it doesn't proceed to the next input box?

Comment: So you mean if the user enters a wrong number it should move to the next inputbox but if the user presses cancel then exit the app?

Comment: If the user enters the wrong number then I'd like the Yes/No message box displayed with the option of trying again. If the user cancels then to exit the app

Comment: There is a slight problem. what happens when the user presses OK and no text is entered. It is slightly difficult to differentiate between `Null Value + Ok` and `Cancel`

Comment: We can use `StrPtr()` to check for cancel but need to know what should be the action if the user presses OK and no text is entered...

Comment: That'll probably be the sticking point then, ideally if the user presses OK I'd like a message box asking them to enter data (in the same way as if they entered the wrong number), is that where it will be difficult to differentiate?

Comment: So basically if the user presses OK and no text is entered you want to reask him to input the number and when the user presses cancel, then exit?

Comment: Yeah that's what I would need

Comment: The cancel function works perfectly but when a correct employee number is entered the message box for 'Invalid Employee Number' comes up

Comment: Check if the employee number actually exists :) I just tested the code and it works...

Comment: I forgot to change the sheet name! When I proceed to the InputBox for Week Ending and press cancel on that, it filters on the employee number, I'm not sure where to place the 'show all data' function in the formula to bring all the data back up again?

Comment: You didn't apply the same logic for the 2nd loop. Remember how we are checking for the cancel button for the 1st loop. You have to do that for the 2nd loop as well :)

Comment: Excellent, that's as good as it's worked so far! The 'Cancel' buttons work, but if I press cancel on the week-ending date inputbox, it filters to the employee number rather than remaining unfiltered

Comment: I believe you are making some kind of typo in your code... please update the final code in the question :)

Comment: Ah I see the error, I've updated the code above which works. One final thing and it should be complete, when entering the 'New Hours' in the InputBox, is it possible to prevent the user entering anything outside the range of 0.1 to 40 hours? Also how do I code it so that if the user presses 'OK' with no data entered, it will prompt Message Box asking them to enter a number?

Comment: `is it possible to prevent the user entering anything outside the range of 0.1 to 40 hours?` No you cannot prevent it but you can check it in code and inform the user. `Also how do I code it so that if the user presses 'OK' with no data entered, it will prompt Message Box asking them to enter a number?` Put a message box in the Else part of `'~~> User pressed OK WITHOUT anything filled`

Comment: I'm not sure which line exactly to place the code in, would you be able to do a follow up just for the final InputBox code? :)

Comment: Which part of the question? 1st part or the 2nd part?

Comment: Just the second part, I'll owe you a big box of mithai after this

Comment: With the last InputBox for 'New Hours' I get a VBA error: 'Loop without Do'. I have tried the remainder of code and it is absolutely perfect. I can't see why it is showing that because the 'Do' statement is there in the code?

Comment: You have `If NewHours <>` in different line Change the `Else
        'User pressed OK WITH something filled
        If NewHours <> "" Then` to `ElseIf NewHours <> ""`

Comment: Tested it all out and it's running smoothly, big +1 :) Thanks for your help and patience